# Javascript loop for dynamic variables (and values) from array without eval

Tags: javascript, variables, eval

i'd like to shorten my code, here is what i want to generate :

```
left_top = {position:"absolute", xPercent:0, yPercent:0, left:"0%", top:"0%"};
left_center = {position:"absolute", xPercent:0, yPercent:-50, left:"0%", top:"50%"};
left_bottom = {position:"absolute", xPercent:0, yPercent:-100, left:"0%", top:"100%"};

center_top = {position:"absolute", xPercent:-50, yPercent:0, left:"50%", top:"0%"};
center_center = {position:"absolute", xPercent:-50, yPercent:-50, left:"50%", top:"50%"};
center_bottom = {position:"absolute", xPercent:-50, yPercent:-100, left:"50%", top:"100%"};

right_top = {position:"absolute", xPercent:-100, yPercent:0, left:"100%", top:"0%"};
right_center = {position:"absolute", xPercent:-100, yPercent:-50, left:"100%", top:"50%"};
right_bottom = {position:"absolute", xPercent:-100, yPercent:-100, left:"100%", top:"100%"};
```

And here is how i do it :

```
var output="";
xPos = ["left", "center", "right"];
yPos = ["top", "center", "bottom"];

for (i=0;i<=2;i++){
    xVal = 50*i;
    for(j=0;j<=2;j++){
        yVal = 50*j;
        eval( xPos[i] + "_" + yPos[j] + " = {position:'absolute', xPercent:" + (-xVal) + ", yPercent:" + (-yVal) + ", left:'" + xVal + "%', top:'" + yVal + "%'}");

    }
}
```

I know that `eval` is a bad practice so how should i proceed?

Thanks a lot

Comment: can I ask why you want to shorten the code? the first example you gave is way more readable and maintainable than the second example...

Comment: @sngregory true. In less there's a lot of cases where you need to run that similar code, there's no need for a loop.

Comment: you could write a function that returns an object

Comment: @sngregory i do some html5 banners and i try to to get the lightest code i can, but you're surely right, i don't gain so much Ko doing this loop...

Comment: My personal philosophy is to prefer readability of my code over the size of the file. You can always use an automated task to minify the source before deploying to production.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this would work:

```
    var output = "";
    xPos = ["left", "center", "right"];
    yPos = ["top", "center", "bottom"];

    var getObj = function (x, y) {
        return { position: "absolute", xPercent: x * - 1, yPercent: y * -1, left: x + '%', top: y + '%' };
    }

    var results = {};

    for (i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {
        xVal = 50 * i;
        for (j = 0; j <= 2; j++) {
            yVal = 50 * j;
            var key = xPos[i] + "_" + yPos[j];
            var obj = getObj(xVal, yVal);
            results[key] = getObj(xVal, yVal);


        }
    }
```

Comment: works fine, now i'll have to understand how...
    results[key] = getObj(xVal, yVal);
results is an object first, it seems very complicated for me the way you use the getObj function then...

Comment: if you can explain the steps, it would be helpful, anyway thanks a lot

Comment: I created the results object as a way to dynamically create psuedo variables as properties on the object. You can use the [] operator on an object to dynamically create/access fields on the object.

It was the only way I could think of to satisfy your requirement of dynamic variable names without using eval.

Comment: I'm really sorry but actually your code don't work.... i forgot to comment the original code :'D

Answer (score 0):

Why not using a function?

```js
const getStyle = (horizontal, vertical) => ({
  position: 'absolute',
  xPercent: horizontal === 'left' ? 0 : horizontal === 'center' ? -50 : -100,
  yPercent: vertical === 'top' ? 0 : vertical === 'center' ? -50 : -100,
  left: horizontal === 'left' ? '0%' : horizontal === 'center' ? '50%' : '100%',
  top: vertical === 'top' ? '0%' : vertical === 'center' ? '50%' : '100%'
});

const left_top = getStyle('left', 'top');
const left_bottom = getStyle('left', 'bottom')
const center_center = getStyle('center', 'center');
// etc.
console.log(left_top, left_bottom, center_center);
```

Just be careful that any unexpected value will fallback to right/bottom.